# How can I create a movable insulated wall?

Tags: walls

I have a storage area which I need a sectioned. The smaller section will be cooled to 35-40 degrees with the help of our air conditioner and an attached [Coolbot](https://www.storeitcold.com/) system.

I want have the option of maximizing this larger storage area, while having an adjustable and insulated accordion door to enclose the cordoned off area when we have the need to keep the area at 35-40 degrees.

We therefore  don't want to permanently wall this area off.  Please offer some options for this project that I can present to our contractor.

Comment: What's on the floor and ceiling?

Comment: At what temp is the other area?

Answer (score 2):

Because your temp differential is relatively high (72˚F vs 35˚F), and you're talking about a relatively large area (I assume, because you talk about accordion "walls"), unless you have a fairly powerful air conditioner or very good wall insulation, your cooling requirements will be challenging.

If it's important that the wall be an accordion wall, then I would think in terms of 2 or 3" thick rigid foam polystyrene wall panels, with edges framed by ¾"x 2(or3)" plywood, with alternating-side hinges linking the individual panels to achieve the accordion effect.

Comment: I like this except I was thinking glue the foam to OSB sheet on just one or both sides and then put on the hinges. Make sure you use glue made for foam insulation. You are basically creating a Stuctural Insulated Panel or SIP yourself. These panels would be quite durable if you put OSB on both sides.

Comment: I agree that laminating OSB on one or both sides of the foam would increase structural rigidity. If light weight is really important, then a plywood "frame" is the lightest technique I could think of. Any other thoughts on this out there?

Answer (score 0):

Alternative suggestion: a [PVC plastic strip wall curtain](http://www.webstaurantstore.com/curtron-m108-pr-4080-40-x-80-polar-reinforced-step-in-refrigerator-freezer-strip-door/517FS102.html?utm_source=Google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=GoogleShopping&gclid=COu8sJK70M0CFQEmhgodR50Cug), like they use for step in refrigerator/freezers in food plants, butchers areas in grocery stores (not sure if you call it a shop, kitchen, or meat locker) or some resturants.

[image]

Comment: These walls are a partial barrier to air flow, and therefor control temperature to some degree, but they cannot resonably be considered *insulated*.

Comment: @bib I pretty much agree with you, but such curtains get used in many places (it's popular because it does work as a fridge door). I considered this possibility to be something overlooked. Suppose this screen is exactly what the OP was asking for, would they have framed the question differently? Knowing the mind and situation of the person asking for help is something that I try to do.

Answer (score 0):

Stick lightweight insulation panels to the back of mobile/wheeled shelving units (or if you have no need for shelving, which would seem odd, just fill the units with insulation and cover the faces.)

The floor and ceiling either need to be VERY uniform/flat, or you need a sizable flexible weatherstrip to fill the larger gap that's required if they are not very uniform/flat.

I would not do this as an accordion - more like a "piston" though possibly still in sections. Depending on the weight of the insulation panels, you may need some "ballast" on the bottom shelf to hold things steady - or move the insulation to the inside back of the shelves, rather than the outside back of the shelves. Go visit a library stack area that has movable bookshelves to get an idea of what can be done if you go whole-hog, though a more limited approach will probably work and fit the budget better. Most likely youtube will save you the need to even visit such a library in person.